# How to dynamically display different components type based on runtime constraints in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

I have a grid component and a dynamically determined second component.

There is a splitter component that always contains a grid in the top part. 
A secondary component will be displayed in the bottom part of the splitter.
The type of secondary component will depend on the selected row type in the grid.
Select row 1 and the secondary component might be line chart
Select row 2 and the secondary component might be another grid...
As the user changes the selected row, the component and the data displayed will need updating.

Any ideas on how to set this up?

Comment: Why can't you simply use `*ngIf` / `[ngSwitch]` directive for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically load second component with `[ngSwitch]` directive.

If you want to dynamically load them, build a code similar to this

```
<div [ngSwitch]="variable">
    <app-first *ngSwitchCase="1"></app-first>
    <app-second *ngSwitchCase="2"></app-second>
</div>
```

It's up to you how you will determine which component should be loaded. You can for example change value of a *variable* with jQuery of plain JavaScript to render specific component. Component will be automatically updated if you change a row.

If you want to automatically update content so the data from 1st component matches 2nd, you have to use some cross component communication provided by **Angular4**. 
Good explanation how to do this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM

Comment: What is the advantage of ngSwitch over ComponentFactoryResolver?